# How to pass a user input in AutoIt Script to WinSCP?

Tags: autoit, winscp

I'm trying to build an FTP transfer script using AutoIt with WinSCP

I'm using winscp.com.

I want to take input from user (via GUI) and then use those inputs in my commands for WinSCP.

For example, I want to set the local directory based on user's choice.

Current Situation: I'm able to store the user's input, however when I try to pass the same in WinSCP command console using AutoIt script, it either doesn't read the variable or simply gives and unknown command error.

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /k ' & 'winscp.com /command  "option batch continue" ' & '"option confirm off" '  & ' "open xyz"' & ' "lcd" ' & $Dir )
```

Where `$Dir` has value for user input stored using `GUICtrlRead()`.

Please suggest if there is any other way to make the WinSCP console read my user data (I want to capture unique data by user every time, so don't want to make a config file).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not know Autoit syntax, I'm pretty sure you have quotes wrong.

Double-quotes have to be around the whole `lcd` command, including its argument. An expanded command have to be like `"lcd /path/to/dir"`, not `"lcd" /path/to/dir`, as you have it now. Just as you have it with the `open` (i.e. `"open xyz"`).

Additionally, had you need to use spaces in the path, the path itself has to be double-quoted. As the quoting happens on a command-line (as opposite to a script file), where double-quotes have their meaning, the in-command double-quotes have to be escaped by doubling them, e.g. the resulting syntax is `"lcd ""/path/to/dir"""`.

So, instead of

```
... ' "lcd" ' & $Dir
```

use

```
... ' "lcd ""' & $Dir & '"""'
```

References:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#syntax

Also I believe you do not really need all those concatenations between constant strings, just do:

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /k winscp.com /command "option batch continue" "option confirm off" "open xyz" "lcd ""' & $Dir & '"""')
```

Comment: I took $Dir outside quotes from "lcd", because i need user input which is stored in variable. And in case of Auto it, if i enclose it within quotes as per your suggestion , the variable would be read as string instead of being read as a varaible

Also since i need to use multiple variables, i have broken up the string for future coding. (once i find a solution to this problem :D

Comment: Did you try my suggestion at all? The double-quotes have nothing to do with AutoIt, they are needed by WinSCP. WinSCP won't understand `"lcd" /path/to/dir`, it needs `"lcd /path/to/dir"`. The single-quotes are AutoIt syntax. And `$Dir` is outside single-quotes in my example.

Comment: Yes, I did , Thanks! It solved half of my problem. I'm able to now use the varaible `$Dir` however i have to manually define it like `$Dir="C:\"` and then the command runs successfully.

However if i pass user input to my variable, i get an error as **too many parameters for lcd**.

    This is what i use for capturing and passing user input

    `$locald = GuiCtrlCreateInput("Local Dir", -1, 10, 130, 20)
                 GUICtrlSetPos($Dir,145,40)
                    $Dir=GUICtrlRead($locald)`

Please advise as i believe im passing the parameters wrong somehow

Comment: He solved your initial question. New one should be posted. Anyway, I dont think path can be used without quotes. A space in the path will be the problem. 
Try putting the path in double quotes too or single quotes.

Comment: Thanks guys, figured out the rest. Thanks for your help!